# expo запускается без ошибок, но при сканировании qr кода на телефоне выводится ошибка "network response timed out"

Tags: react-native, expo

expo запускается без ошибок, но при сканировании qr кода на телефоне выводится ошибка "network response timed out" а при нажатии w без проблем запускается в браузере [image: запускается без варнингов]